# How to infer the corner of the group?

Tags: sketchup

I have tried many different things but I have not found a way to infer to the point selected by red circle.

[image]

Comment: Non-programming questions about SketchUp are better posted at the [SketchUp Forums](http://forums.sketchup.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`BoundingBox.corner(n)`](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/boundingbox#corner) in which `n`:

```
0 = [0, 0, 0] (left front bottom)
1 = [1, 0, 0] (right front bottom)
2 = [0, 1, 0] (left back bottom)
3 = [1, 1, 0] (right back bottom)
4 = [0, 0, 1] (left front top)
5 = [1, 0, 1] (right front top)
6 = [0, 1, 1] (left back top)
7 = [1, 1, 1] (right back top))
```

If you `group` is your Group and you want the left front bottom corner::

```
group.local_bounds.corner(0)
```

Comment: Here is the SketchUp Ruby API url for BoundingBox #corner -> [Click Here](https://ruby.sketchup.com/Geom/BoundingBox.html#corner-instance_method)